# Defining a NSFetchedResultsController's scope?

Tags: ios, core-data

Let's say I have a Core Data model, with a graph that looks like this:

Book->Chapter->Page

and I want to pull up some Pages.  Is there a way to restrict a NSFetchedResultsController's scope to the contents of the "pages" to-many relationship (NSSet) of a given Chapter?

One workaround way is with a predicate (only return Pages whose chapter inverse matches the Chapter I want), but won't the fetch have to search through ALL the Page objects in the store? Seems like it'd be better to just tell the fetch "only work with items in this NSSet".

Caching is out of the question.  Too many horror stories...

Any ideas?  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to find out what the result would be.
It's to do it and profile / test it.

If you are using an NSFetchedResultsController, do the predicate where chapter matches, as well as the book name.
If you are concerned about efficiency, make sure that the key you are fetching / predicating are indexed.

If the result is to slow, that will be the time to think about optimization.

Comment: Was afraid of that.  Ah well time for optimizations. :)